# Why the docker container returning the cached value?

Tags: docker, nestjs

I have created a basic nestjs application.
At root level `Dockerfile` and `compose.yaml` file is defined.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.* /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

`compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  app: 
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/
    ports:
      - 4001:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - mysql
  mongodb:
    container_name: app-mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:example
    volumes:
      - app-mongodb:/data/db
    ports:
      - 4003:27017
  mysql:
    container_name: app-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db 
      - MYSQL_USER=user 
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password 
    volumes:
      - app-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 4002:3306
volumes:
  app-data:
  app-mongodb:
  app-mysql:
```

I build application using `docker compose build --build`.
Application starts successfully, but when i hit the any endpoint it written the old response.

1. I deleted all the relate images and container
2. started with `docker compose up --build` command

Comment: Suggestion to optimise *Dockerfile* and  *compose.yaml* file willl be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the volumes?

Comment: The mount (`- app-data:/app/`) is unnecessary since you include this in your `Dockerfile`. You're adding the updated files and **then** overwriting them with an existing (!) volume (`app-data`). Unless you need `app-data` for something else, just remove the reference in the Docker Compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this block:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/
```

You should generally not mount anything over the source code or built application in an image.

If you use a Docker named volume (or an anonymous volume), then you get the behavior you see.  The first time it apparently works successfully, but what happens under the hood is that Docker first creates an empty volume and then copies the image content into it.  If you run the container again, the volume already has content in it, and Docker does not try to update it.  This results in the behavior you see, where the old image content (from the volume) is visible even though you've updated the volume.

If you use any other kind of mount – a bind mount of a host directory, a Kubernetes volume – nothing will ever get copied into the mounted storage, even on first use, and this will fail the first time rather than the second time.

Since your application is already built into the image, you don't need a volume mount here, and it's safe to just delete this block entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, however i tried with deleting the block. 
```volumes:
      - app-data:/app/```
But after deleting it, i need to rebuild my container for updated change to reflect. 
No dought chnages are reflecting but it requires rebuilt

Comment: ```volumes: 
          - .:/app
```
It worked for me,

Comment: Rebuilding your image when you change the source code is normal.  A Docker container is an isolated environment, and by design the container can't normally see the source files on your host system.